# List Objectify 4 entities in order (but without filtering)

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am just getting started with Objectify 4 and have defined this class:

```
@Entity
@Cache 
public class Project {  
    @Id    public long   id;
    @Index public String name;
}
```

I have saved three such entities and would like to list them sorted by name.

What I observe is the following: if I iterate over `ofy().load().type(Project.class).list()` I get all three (but unsorted, obviously), however if I iterate over `ofy().load().type(Project.class).order("name").list()` I get only one (apparently the middle one).

What is going on here? How can I list all entities sorted by name (without a filter)? I've noticed that another example uses [parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486635/how-to-sort-responses-in-objectify): is this a requirement for this kind of sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you saved the other two entities before you added the @Index annotation. If you want the indexes to be updated, re-save the entities.